# Populating foreign key on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I have a Evaluation similar to this:

**Evaluation.rb**

```
has_one :cardio
has_one :neuro
```

**Cardio.rb**

```
belongs_to :evaluation
```

**Neuro.rb**

```
belongs_to :evaluation
```

My evaluation controller is similar to this:

```
  def create
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    @evaluator = Evaluator.find(session[:evaluator_id]) if session[:evaluator_id]
    @evaluation = Evaliation.new(:patient_id => @patient.id, :evaluator_id => @evaluator.id)
    @neuro = Neuro.new(:evaluation_id => @evaluation.id)
    @cardio = Cardio.new(:evaluation_id => @evaluation.id)
    if (@evaluation.save! && @neuro.save! && @cardio.save!)

      redirect_to evaluation_path(@evaluation.id), :notice => "Evaluation created"

    else
      render ("new") 
    end
  end
```

When the evaluation is created the cardio and neuro are created too, but with null evaluation_id.
I tried to move the `@cardio = Cardio.new(:evaluation_id => @evaluation.id)` inside the `if` but it didnt worked too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@evaluation` won't have an id set until you save it, so @evaluation.id will be nil when you are creating `@neuro` and `@cardio`. In other words:

```
@evaluation = ...

if (@evaluation.save!)
  @neuro = Neuro.new(:evaluation_id => @evaluation.id)
  @cardio = Cardio.new(:evaluation_id => @evaluation.id)

  if (@neuro.save! && @cardio.save!)
    redirect_to evaluation_path(@evaluation.id), :notice => "Evaluation created"
  else
    render ("new")
  end

else
  render ("new") 
end
```

Comment: Thanks man, its working. But lets say I have 7 or 8 more evaluation types (cardio,neuro, field tests etc) is there a more "pretty" way to do it or I will have to set the foreing keys manually like I made on `@cardio`and `@neuro`?

Comment: I can't remember if this works in rails 2.x, but in rails3, you can do @evaluation = Evaluation.new(..., :neuro => Neuro.new, :cardio => Cardio.new), and all the objects will be saved in a transaction-like manner.

Comment: Dont know if it works for me, I belive my relations are wrong (should have the forein keys on evaluation). Thanks a lot Adam, I will try to fix this.